# How to always show share counter for AddThis?

Tags: javascript, php, share, addthis, social-media

I am using AddThis to show social media share buttons. I have used the "Sharing Buttons" tool and I have selected the option to show share counts. However, I believe the count is shown only if there is a significant amount of share.

My question is: Is it possible to **always** have the share buttons display the share counts even if it is zero?

Here's the code that I got from AddThis:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" async="async"></script>
<div class="addthis_sharing_toolbox"></div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Share the code that you are including, because I am using addthis and it works fine

Comment: There is no code per se. You just have to follow the steps in AddThis and it gives a ready made code to you which you just have to put in your file. It works fine for me too, however, the counter does not show if the share is too less. The counters appear only after a significant amount of shares.

Comment: AddThis gives you a code. Share it please. It's important to see what component are you including.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I have edited the question to include the code.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the JavaScript Console? Do you have any other JavaScript code in your solution that might interfere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want custom share buttons, you can make something like this: (this code is that I've been used in various projects, and it works fine. It only includes facebook, twitter and g+ but you can add all resources dispossed in addThis)

```
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="40%"><a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a></td>
            <td width="30%"><a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a></td>
            <td width="30%"><a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:annotation="bubble" g:plusone:size="medium"></a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <script>window.___gcfg = {lang: "es"};</script>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></script>
```